# How to create ssh trusts in batches?

Tags: linux

How to use "shell programming" to use a text (including the host and password that needs to be trusted) to implement a batch of ssh passwordless login trust between multiple servers?

Comment: Are you asking how to distribute .ssh/known_hosts?

Comment: No, what I want to know is how to use a host ssh-copy-id to send the public key to N hosts.

Comment: so writing loop in a shell script?

Comment: yes, but you need to interact with the script because  need to enter the password of the target host.